# is it possible to send notifications every time a file is added to a folder

Tags: icloud

I want to be able to send the person I am sharing a folder with to get notification every time a file is added to the folder. Please let me know if that is possible. Thanks

Comment: This can be answered with a simple "Yes" :-) Is the other person using a Mac? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi Elroy and welcome to Apple.SE! Please [edit] your question such that it becomes a [good question™](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) that others can help you with.

Comment: What OS versions are both computers using? Are you just using normal file sharing?

Comment: What kinda of notification? Email? Push? SMS?